# Why do my favorites show recent updates, when I can't find what's been updated?

Tags: support, bookmarks, recent-activity, updating-questions

Whenever the "favorites" tab on my user profile turns blue, indicating that something's changed, I flip over to it to see what's been updated. I sort my favorites by "recent", and my understanding is that the most recently changed questions should float to the top. However, even though my favorites page shows recent activity, I often can not find anything in the question that has changed at all.

Here's an example from today. When I sort my favorites page by "recent", I see this as the top question:

[image: "Accesing the Android media stream for audio visualization" - last updated 13h ago]

According to this, the question was updated 13 hours ago, by a user named "I could't use snoop". 13 hours ago would be approximately midnight EDT, September 8, 2011. So, where's the update? When I visit [the question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571814/accessing-the-android-media-stream-for-audio-visualization) and look for the update, I don't see anything from this *year*, let alone the last 13 hours.

Here's a screenshot of [what that page looked like when I asked this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0m3V.png), in case it changes. I looked at all comments, answers, and the question itself. I looked at the edit history. I don't see anything new at all! And this happens a lot. This question is just the most recent example. Can anyone explain this? Is it a bug?

Comment: Give [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3571814/timeline), I would say you're correct and it's a bug.

Comment: It's possible that the user posted a question-as-an-answer, which was deleted and later [reposted as an actual question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342845/mediaplayer-snoop-on-android). Deletion counts as activity, although not everyone can observe it. I'm not sure if that was the case here or not, though.

Comment: @Tim Stone - Could be, but if so the fact that the activity still shows up on my recent favorites page would still be a bug, I think.

Comment: @Tim: As far as I know, it's not the deletion that counts as activity, but the last edit of the deleted question (which could even be _after_ the deletion). But that's a minor issue here, of course.

Comment: @Joshua: I don't know if it's a _bug_, but it's definitely not helpful design. There's another longstanding annoying issue: comments to the question give favorite notifications, but don't count as activity. So on 10 January you should have gotten a favorite notification on that question, without the question being at the top of your favorites (sorted by activity).

Answer (score 1):

The answer was provided and then flagged and deleted as not an answer.

This is not unusual...

Comment: It appears then that no mention or record of deleted answers show up for me in the question timeline, or in the question itself. There's no record of it whatsoever there. That being the case, shouldn't there also be no record of it in my favorites activity? It seems to me that listing activity I can't see on the favorites page is a bug, or at least bad design.

Comment: you can see it if you have 10k rep; visibility into deleted questions and answers is available then.

Comment: Right, so, until then it shouldn't appear on my favorites page, is what I'm saying. Why are the criteria different?